# How to set system properties of embedded tomee?

Tags: java, openejb, apache-tomee

I have read this link:
[Embedded Configuration](http://tomee.apache.org/embedded-configuration.html) and i am trying to set "openejb.deployments.classpath=true"

this is my code:

```
public class Run {

private static EJBContainer ejbContainer;

public static void main( String[] args ) throws NamingException, InterruptedException, IOException {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty(EJBContainer.PROVIDER, "tomee-embedded");
    props.setProperty("openejb.deployments.classpath", "true");
    ejbContainer = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(props);

}
```

}

pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomee-embedded</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

But i still get outputs like:

```
INFO - openejb configuration file is 'C:\cygwin\tmp\apache-tomee1917201117325246334-home\conf\openejb.xml'
INFO - Configuring Service(id=Tomcat Security Service, type=SecurityService, provider-id=Tomcat Security Service)
INFO - Configuring Service(id=Default Transaction Manager, type=TransactionManager, provider-id=Default Transaction Manager)
INFO - Using 'openejb.system.apps=false'
INFO - Using 'openejb.deployments.classpath=false'
INFO - Creating TransactionManager(id=Default Transaction Manager)
```

Did i miss something?

Answer (score 0):

tomee embedded sets this property later (after tomee is started and this is logged when tomee starts). So your property is correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the property before you start the container.

```
...
System.setProperty("openejb.deployments.classpath", "true");

Properties props = new Properties();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you do it is absolutely right.

```
new Properties();
props.setProperty(EJBContainer.PROVIDER, "tomee-embedded");
props.setProperty("openejb.deployments.classpath", "true");
ejbContainer = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(props);
```

But you overlooked that you also have set a configuration file. You can see it in the log.

```
INFO - openejb configuration file is 'C:\cygwin\tmp\apache...
```

So make sure your configuration file is not overwriting your programmatically settings.

Comment: Where can one set this property in code in a container-managed environment? As far as I know the container is already started as soon as I have any code control..

Comment: @Amalgovinus you can use the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

side note: TomEE Embedded EJBContainer has no good classpath deployment (it deploys modules/jar/configured war(s))

Maybe have a look to Container class of tomee embedded which supports classpath deployment in a bit more recent releases than 1.6.